# Having trouble linking file

Tags: modeling, mesh, linked-data, append, scale

Hello I seem to have lost my mesh data upon appending the file. The materials work and load correctly but the model itself is only a box now. I can view and edit the original model fine in the original file but linking or appending the file only leads to a box mesh. The other objects in scene come over correctly... or at least they used to.

I also don't know what happened to the scale, considering I did not change the grid I would have thought they would end up the same size. I had recently applied scale changes to the model and fear by applying the set scale I have corrupted the model.

Is there anything that can be done or what I be better off starting over? I will note that exporting luckily has the model export correctly and at the right scale, though I don't know how to reapply blender materials... As they don't come over with the same materials in a fbx format.

....

It appears if I merely duplicate my board in the original file it imports correctly, does anyone have an idea as to why? I have a second question, is it possible to unlock it so I can rotate it in scene? Linking and appending won't do much good if my models are frozen in place. :/ I suppose I can probably just duplicate the linked files duplicate and use that...

Though I still would like to know the correct way to deal with linking and appending files instead of duplicating things until I'm able to get them to work correctly because with a lot of files this could become very troublesome.

[image: Here is my model in the original file]

[image: Here is me linking the model in another scene]

[image: Here you can see I applied the scale and transform, I thought that would clean up the model but I seem to be mistaken.]

[image: Here I added in a duplicated board I created in the original file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For library linking use groups. Let's I show an example:

In library file select all part in your object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. And in side <kbd>T</kbd>-menu or in <kbd>F6</kbd> set name of the group:

[image]

In main scene file add group to the scene. It's like adding object, but you select "group" instead of "object".

After this you will get an empty object with duplication of linked group, that you can move, rotate and scale as a regular object:

[image]

And also you will get this instance in add menu:

[image]